# Can the "frostythesnowman" tag be amended?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

For consistency across the site, can I ask for a tag to be amended on [this question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/20008/the-hat-or-christmas-snow).

The tag is [frostythesnowman](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/frostythesnowman).

I suggest changing to "frosty-the-snowman", which is easier to read and consistent with other tags on the site. I can't change it though, as the site detects it is too similar to what is already there.

Obviously this is a teeny weeny minor issue, but a change would be appreciated.

Comment: Hah, by coincidence at the exact moment you posted this question, I flagged that *Frosty* question for moderator attention in order to change the tag (which would actually have sufficed, since this is not really debatable anyway). I've issued such a flag often enough, it sucks that you can't add hyphens right away.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson: Good thinking. I took it to meta as per the suggestion on the pop up. A moderator flag would have been much simpler as, like you said, there's no real discussion here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been done

And now some padding to make it long enough.